# Question about Voyager, Pioneer and other space programs

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I always wondered what kind of cameras the space probes have. Like megapixel count, sensor size, lens length, that kind of stuff.

Would it be off topic in this SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may or may not be on topic here.

It's *definitely* on topic at the new [Astronomy.SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com), though. I suspect you'd be likely to find more targeted expertise on that site, so I strongly suggest you ask it there.

See [Astronomy SE questions tagged astrophotography or  photography](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*photograph*).